How to make a table in QTextEdit resizable?
I've created a class called CustomTextEdit that derives from QTextEdit. The derived class is going to be used in a  larger project and lets users insert tables through a menu action. The problem I face is that the program does not allow users to drag and resize the table like they can in MS Word. When the user hovers the mouse pointer over a column, the cursor must change to Qt. SplitHCursor and dragging one of the columns must resize it. I also want to detect if the table is in focus so that I can make the program show options to edit the table (like insert above, insert below).
I tried something like this. But it does not work.
def insert_table(self):
    dialog = QInputDialog.getText(
        self, "Table",
        "Enter the number of rows and columns seperated by commas")
    cursor = QCursor(Qt.SplitHCursor)
    pos = cursor.pos()
    details, value = dialog
    self.format = QTextTableFormat()
    self.format.setColumnWidthConstraints([QTextLength(QTextLength.PercentageLength, 10.0)]*int(details.split(",")[1]))
    rows, columns = tuple(details.split(","))
    self.cursorPosition = self.editor.textCursor()
    self.table = self.cursorPosition.insertTable(int(rows), int(columns))
    self.table.setFormat(self.format)


Unfortunately, what you're asking is not simple to achieve, and your code practically does nothing of what you asked, except from creating the table. You'll need to work with a QTextEdit subclass with mouse tracking enabled and implement its mouse handlers (especially the mouseMoveEvent which will change the mouse cursor or the table properties depending on its pressed buttons), but you shall do more studying about the QTextCursor and QTextDocument API. To detect if the text cursor is in a table, just connect to the cursorPositionChanged and check the current cursor's blockFormat() type.
